# "derefeerncing pointer to incomplete type" - trying to make tree nodes in animal guessing game C

Tags: c, malloc, binary-search-tree

**main:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    printf("Please think of an animal. I will try to find out what it is by asking you some yes/no questions.");
    struct treenode *root = mkTreeNode("Is it a reptile?\n", NULL, NULL);
    struct treenode *selectedNode = root;
    root->left = mkTreeNode("Does it have legs?\n", NULL, NULL);
    root->right = mkTreeNode("Is it a mammal?\n", NULL, NULL);
    root->left->left = mkTreeNode("Crocodile", NULL, NULL);
    root->right->left = mkTreeNode("Elephnt", NULL, NULL);
```

**mkTreeNode:**

```
struct treenode {
 char *animal;
 struct treenode *left;
 struct treenode *right;
};

struct treenode *mkTreeNode(char *str, struct treenode *lChild, struct treenode *rChild) {

struct treenode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));

  node -> left = lChild;
  node -> right = rChild;
  node -> animal = str;

  return node;
}
```

I get an error on line 6 in main

```
root->left = mkTreeNode("Does it have legs?\n", NULL, NULL);
```

"dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"; any ideas? Do I need another `malloc` or something?

Comment: You need to **think about** the error message. How **possibly** could a **compiler error** have to do anything with a run-time thing? (e. g. whether or not the pointer points to memory allocated using `malloc()`?)

Answer (score 1):

If the code shown is in different files, then it's not clear if the `struct` declaration is visible from the C file that has `main()` in it. If it isn't, you get that error when trying to access fields of the structure.

*UPDATE* You say that it's all in one file, although it doesn't look like that. In that case, note that order matters, the `struct` declaration must appear before (above) `main()`.

Basically, this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct treenode {
 char *animal;
 struct treenode *left;
 struct treenode *right;
};

struct treenode *mkTreeNode(char *str, struct treenode *lChild, struct treenode *rChild)
{
  struct treenode *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
  node->left = lChild;
  node->right = rChild;
  node->animal = str;
  return node;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
  printf("Please think of an animal. I will try to find out what it is by asking you some yes/no questions.");
  struct treenode *root = mkTreeNode("Is it a reptile?\n", NULL, NULL);
  struct treenode *selectedNode = root;
  root->left = mkTreeNode("Does it have legs?\n", NULL, NULL);
  root->right = mkTreeNode("Is it a mammal?\n", NULL, NULL);
  root->left->left = mkTreeNode("Crocodile", NULL, NULL);
  root->right->left = mkTreeNode("Elephant", NULL, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In that case put the treenode struct in a .h file and include it in both c files.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply

they are all in 1 file, how can i avoid this error?

Comment: @user3364844 Show the entire file, assuming it's not very much larger than what you have now. It's very confusing since you've presented it as if there are two different files.

Comment: oh sorry i think i misread the reply.. i already declared struct before main:

struct treenode *mkTreeNode(char *str, struct treenode *lChild, struct treenode *rChild);

Comment: @user3364844 That is not a declaration of the structure, only of the `mkTreeNode()` function, it says nothing about the members of the `struct treenode` structure.